# Best way to create objects with objects inside

Tags: python

I need to create a system of objects which in turn have objects inside, for example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 'Message from class A'

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = A()
```

or do it in this way

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.B = A()

    class A(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.A = 'Message from class A'
```

so I can't use it like

```
>>> C = B()
>>> print C.B.A
# Message from class A
```

what is the best choice of these two, or if there is something else, please welcome!

**EDIT 1** current piece of code

```
class Foam(object):
    def __init__(self, rotor, path='OpenFoamCase'):
        self.dirs = {}
        self.path = path
        self.rotor = rotor
        self.rotorObj = Rotor(rotor)

        # OpenFoam case directories
        self.dirs['main'] = path if path.endswith('/') else path + '/'
        self.dirs['system'] = path + '/system/'
        self.dirs['constant'] = path + '/constant/'
        self.dirs['geometry'] = path + '/geometry/'
        self.dirs['polyMesh'] = path + '/constant/polyMesh/'
        self.dirs['triSurface'] = path + '/constant/triSurface/'

        self.__openFoamInit()
        self.mesh = OpenFoamBlockMesh(self)

class OpenFoamBlockMesh(object):
    def __init__(self, study):
       self.airfoil_offset = 0.5  
       self.rotor_disk_length = [20, 20]

        ...
    def box(self):
        ...
```

so now I’m using it as:

```
study = Foam(rotor=rotor, path='OpenFoamCase_Tesis')
study.mesh.airfoil_offset = 0.02 
study.mesh.rotor_disk_length = [2, 2.5] 
study.mesh.box()
```

Comment: pythontonic or pythonic?

Comment: Could you provide some context? As it stands, it's not clear why you'd do either.

Comment: There isn't anything really pythonic about the question. It is a general Object Oriented design question. Do you want an object composition (way one), or an inner class (way two)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok  i'm going to put part of my code

Comment: class A(B):   # try inheritance.

Comment: it depends. rules of thumb - resort to first way unless you have very good reason to go second way

Comment: @cricket_007 I don’t know i trying to peek one of them

Comment: Are you trying to "hide" class A behind class B? If not, then there is no reason to put it as an inner class.

Comment: [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: @JaredGoguen haha thanks for the path correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your purpose. If the `A` class is just a helper class for `B`, and is a simple and small class, you can use the second method (inner class).

If the class `A`, might be used for others classes or is a big class, is recommended to use the first method (simple composition).

If you provide a better example of your real world problem, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: I edit my question with a pice of my code the two are bigger class

Comment: @efirvida I'd recommend you to stick with the first approach (class composition)